# When filing US income taxes separately, who can claim new home purchase?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, first-time-home-buyer

Alice and Bob are unmarried and purchased a house together as joint tenants. Both of their names are on the home title and both are on the mortgage.

Who can claim the following on their income tax:

1. First time home buyer credit
2. Deductions for interest
3. Deductions for Taxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The person who actually paid the taxes, mortgage interest, etc. would be the one that could claim the respective deductions.

For the first time home buyer credit see [IRS Notice 2009-12](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-drop/n-09-12.pdf) page3 excerpted here:

> If two or more taxpayers who are not married purchase a principal
>   residence and otherwise satisfy the requirements, the first-time 
>   homebuyer credit may be allocated between the taxpayers using any
>   reasonable method.  A reasonable method is any method that does not
>   allocate any portion of the credit to a taxpayer not eligible to claim
>   that portion.
>
> A reasonable method includes allocating the credit between taxpayers
>   who are eligible to claim the credit based on (1) the taxpayers’
>   contributions towards the purchase price of a residence as tenants in
>   common or joint tenants, or (2) the taxpayers’ ownership interests in
>   a residence as tenants in common.

This can get really complicated, because the law has changed over the years and each person could have a different status of "first time homeowner". Here are some examples from the notice to help:

> These examples illustrate how the first-time homebuyer credit
>   may be allocated when A and B purchase a principal residence as
>   tenants in common.  The rules illustrated in the examples also apply
>   in a similar manner to taxpayers who purchase a principal residence as
>   joint tenants.  Unless otherwise indicated, assume that in each
>   example A  and B (i) purchase a principal residence on May 1, 2008,
>   (ii) are not married to each other, (iii) do not have MAGI in excess 
>   of the MAGI threshold, and (iv) are first-time homebuyers who
>   otherwise satisfy the requirements of § 36.
>
> **Example 1.** A contributes $45,000 and B contributes $15,000 towards the
>   $60,000 purchase price of a residence.  Each owns a one-half  interest
>   in the residence as tenants in common.  The allowable credit is
>   limited to 10 percent of the purchase price, or $6,000.   A and B may
>   allocate the allowable $6,000 credit three-fourths to A and one-fourth
>   to B based on their contributions toward the purchase price of the
>   residence, one-half to each based on their ownership interests in the
>   residence, or using any other reasonable method (for example, the
>   entire credit to A or B because both A and B are eligible to claim the
>   entire allowable credit).
>
> **Example 2.** A contributes $10,000 for a down payment towards the
>   $100,000 purchase price of a residence, and A and B obtain and are
>   jointly liabl e for a $90,000 mortgage for the remainder of the
>   purchase price.  Each owns a one-half interest in the residence as
>   tenants in common.  The allowable credit is not $10,000 (10 percent of
>   the purchase price) but is limited to $7,500.  A and B may allocate
>   the  5 allowable $7,500 credit 55 percent to A and 45 percent to B
>   based on their contributions toward the purchase price, one-half to
>   each based on their ownership interests in the residence, or using any
>   other reasonable method (for example, the entire credit to  A or B
>   because both A and B are eligible to claim the entire allowable
>   credit).
>
> **Example 3.** On April 15, 2008, A pays the entire $100,000 purchase
>   price of a residence and is the sole owner.  Under § 36(b)(1)(A), the
>   allowable credit is not $10,000 (10 percent of the purchase price) but
>   is limited to $7,500.  On May 12, 2008, A transfers a one-half
>   interest in the residence to B as a tenant in common for $10,000.  A
>   may claim the entire allowable $7,500 credit.  Because B  acquired B’s
>   interest in the residence from Ain part by gift, B’s basis in the
>   residence is determined under § 1015 by reference to  A’s basis in the
>   residence.  Therefore, B did not purchase an interest in the residence
>   within the meaning of § 36(c)(3), and no portion of the credit may be
>   allocated to B because B is not eligible to claim any portion of the
>   credit.
>
> **Example 4.**  A and B each contributes $50,000 towards the $100,000
>   purchase price of a residence and owns a one-half interest in the
>   residence as tenants in common.  The allowable credit is not $10,000
>   (10 percent of the purchase price) but is limited to $7,500.  However,
>   B  is not a first-time homebuyer within the meaning of § 36(c)(1). 
>   Therefore, no portion of the credit may be allocated to B  because B
>   is not eligible to claim any portion of the credit.  A may claim the
>   entire allowable $7,500 credit.
>
> **Example 5.** A contributes $75,000 and B contributes $25,000 towards the
>   $100,000 purchase price of a residence, and each owns a one-half 
>   interest in the residence as tenants in common.  The allowable credit
>   is not $10,000 (10 percent of the purchase price) but is limited to
>   $7,500.  A’s MAGI is $100,000 and B’s MAGI is $60,000.  Because A’s
>   MAGI exceeds the $95,000 MAGI cap, any portion of the credit allocated
>   to A would be reduced to $0.  A and B may allocate the entire
>   allowable $7,500 credit to B because B’s MAGI is less than the $75,000
>   MAGI threshold and, therefore, B is eligible to claim the entire
>   allowable credit.
>
> **Example 6.** A and B each contributes $50,000 towards the $100,000
>   purchase price of a residence and owns a one-half interest in the
>   residence as tenants in common.  Under § 36(b)(1)(A), the allowable
>   credit is not $10,000 (10 percent of the purchase price) but is
>   limited to $7,500.  A’s MAGI is $80,000 and B’s MAGI is $60,000. 
>   Because A’s MAGI exceeds the $75,000 MAGI threshold by $5,000, any
>   portion of the allowable credit allocated to A will be reduced by
>   one-quarter, $5,000 (MAGI in excess of $75,000) / $20,000.  A and B
>   may allocate the allowable $7,500 credit one-half to A and one-half to
>   B ($3,750 each) based on their contributions toward the purchase price
>   of the residence or their ownership interests in the residence. 
>   However, A’s $3,750 portion of the credit is limited by § 36(b)(2) and
>   is reduced by one-quarter ($3,750 x .25 = $937.50) to 7 $2,812.50
>   ($3,750 - 937.50).  Alternatively, A and B may allocate the allowable
>   $7,500 credit using any other reasonable method (for example, the
>   entire credit to B because B’s MAGI is less than the $75,000 MAGI
>   threshold and, therefore, B is eligible to claim the entire allowable
>   credit).
>
> **Example 7.** A and B, who are sisters, each contributes $50,000 towards
>   the $100,000 purchase price of a residence and each owns a one-half
>   interest as tenants in common.  The allowable credit is not $10,000
>   (10 percent of the purchase price) but is limited to $7,500.   A and B
>   purchase the residence from their cousin, C.  A, B, and C are not
>   related persons within the meaning of § 36(c)(5).  herefore, A and B
>   may allocate the allowable $7,500 credit one-half to A and one-half to
>   B based on their contributions toward the purchase price of the
>   residence or their ownership interests in the residence.
>   Alternatively, A and B may allocate the allowable $7,500 credit using
>   any other reasonable method (for example, the entire credit to A or B
>   because both A and B are eligible to claim the entire allowable
>   credit).

Comment: *facepalm* yeah, makes sense. I've edited the question for clarity, removing the unnecessary parts. I also added one last part to the question (first time home buyer credit). Thanks!

Comment: @zashu Updated my answer. That wrinkle added a lot of complexity.